# Insert to a blank XML column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2019

Using SQL Server 2019, trying to update a load of products on our system, with a origin code, 29k rows have no value at the moment, this column is stored in XML Data, other XML columns do have data, which changes per product.

I have tried an Update which works fine but when it comes to inserting it fails.

Current Code Below:

```
DECLARE @nameElement VARCHAR(30) = 'Origin';
UPDATE Products SET CustomColumns.modify('replace value of (/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[Name=sql:variable("@nameElement")]/Value/text())[1] with ("285")')WHERE ProductID = '001SP9000'
```

Current data format.

```
<CustomColumnsCollection>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>RequiresCore</Name>
    <DataType>5</DataType>
    <Value>False</Value>
  </CustomColumn>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>Core</Name>
    <DataType>4</DataType>
    <Value />
  </CustomColumn>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>Origin</Name>
    <DataType>4</DataType>
    <Value />
  </CustomColumn>
</CustomColumnsCollection>
```

The Insert I have tried is:

```
UPDATE Products SET CustomColumns.modify('Insert (/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[Name=sql:variable("@nameElement")]/Value/text())[1] with ("285")')WHERE ProductID = '001SP9000'
```

Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say that the `INSERT` is failing; what is the `INSERT` statement you are using? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hello Larnu, I have tried an update from the above which just fails as no value exists, the script completes but does nothing. If that makes sense?

Comment: *" I have tried an update from the above which just fails as no value exists"* that isn't what you say in the question: *"I have tried an Update which works fine but when it comes to inserting it fails."* Which is it, an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` that is failing? Update your question accordingly. And, like I said, if the statement is failing include the error.

Comment: Updated with more info, It is a combo of both, an Update to existing data but inserting data into a specific xml column.

Comment: And what is the error...?

Comment: No error, as it says "Command completed successfully" but no data is actually inserted or updated.

Comment: Then why say it fails? If there isn't an error, the statement isn't failing..

Comment: Ok, fails may be the wrong term but it incorrectly updates/inserts, which is where I am looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now resolved with the below.

```
DECLARE @nameElement VARCHAR(30) = 'Origin';
UPDATE dbo.Products
SET Customcolumns.modify('
        insert text{"248"}
        into ((/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[Name=sql:variable("@nameElement")]/Value))[1]
        ')
        WHERE ProductID = '001SP9000'
        and Customcolumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[Name=sql:variable("@nameElement")]/Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') is null
```